# Get GridView selected row DataKey in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview

I have GridView which I can select a row. I then have a button above the grid called Edit which the user can click to popup a window and edit the selected row. So the button will have Javascript code behind it along the lines of

```
function editRecord()
{
  var gridView = document.getElementById("<%= GridView.ClientID %>");
  var id = // somehow get the id here ???
  window.open("edit.aspx?id=" + id);
}
```

The question is how do I retrieve the selected records ID in javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I worked it out based on JasonS response. What I did was create a hidden field in the Grid View like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("JobID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="select" Text="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then on the OnRowDataBind have code to set the selected row

```
protected virtual void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Click to highlight row
        Control lnkSelect = e.Row.FindControl("lnkSelect");
        if (lnkSelect != null)
        {
            StringBuilder click = new StringBuilder();
            click.AppendLine(m_View.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(lnkSelect, String.Empty));
            click.AppendLine(String.Format("onGridViewRowSelected('{0}')", e.Row.RowIndex));
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", click.ToString());
        }
    }            
}
```

And then in the Javascript I have code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedRowIndex = null;

function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIndex)
{        
    selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
}

function editItem()
{   
    if (selectedRowIndex == null) return;

    var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');                
    var cell = gridView.rows[parseInt(selectedRowIndex)+1].cells[0];        
    var hidID = cell.childNodes[0];        
    window.open('JobTypeEdit.aspx?id=' + hidID.value);
}

</script>
```

Works a treat :-)

Comment: That's basically how I do this.

Comment: what is m_View i don t know wat i want to put in that place

Comment: You can probably just get rid of m_View and it should work. This code was using MVP pattern and was a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

1) change your javascript function to use a parameter

```
function editRecord(clientId)
{ ....
```

2) output the call in your editRecord button... if you want to avoid dealing with the .net generated ids, just use a simple

```
<input type="button" onclick="editRecord(your-rows-client-id-goes-here)" />
```

Comment: This works if I have an edit button on every row. But I only have 1 edit button on the whole page on a toolbar above the grid. So the workflow is someone selects a record and then clicks edit on the toolbar. There is no way to pass the id to the editRecord function.

Comment: how can i get the rows client id here, Dave?

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your comments to @DaveK's response, in javascript you can set the id of a hidden field to the clientId of the selected row when the user selects it.  Then have your editRecord function use the value set on the hidden form field.

Answer (score 0):

one could avoid javascript altogether, by setting anchor tags pre-populated with the query string for each row (although this will effect your table layout, it will need only one click rather than 2 from the user)

insert in the gridview template:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="editLink" Target="_blank"
   NavigateURL='<%# Eval("JobID","edit.aspx?id={0}") %>'> 
     Edit..
</asp:HyperLink>
```