# Creating Dynamic controls based on the selected value of a static control

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list holding some choices. Based on user selection I need to create some dynamic controls and render them on the form.

My understanding is that dynamic controls need to be created in OnInit or in CreateChildControls so that the ViewState for these dynamic controls is restored correctly by the runtime.

The problem is, I am unable to get the SelectedValue of the dropdown in OnInit or CreateChildControls since the ViewState has not been restored for the dropdown as yet.

Is there any way to obtain the current selection so that I can create the dynamic controls based on the current user selection and add them the page correctly

EDIT:
The markup looks as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="(Select Color)" Value="" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="Red" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="Green" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="Blue" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plHolder" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        if (ddl.Text != "")
        {
            tb.Text = ddl.Text;
            if (Session["id"] != null)
            {
                string id = Session["id"].ToString();
                tb.ID = id;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["id"] = tb.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
            }
            plHolder.Controls.Add(tb);
        }

    }
}
```

On the line "tb.Text = ddl.Text;" I'm hoping to get the current selection and based on that set the value of the text property for the dynamic control. But the current selection has not been set yet since it's in OnInit.

Comment: you need to post some code to check where is the problem, According to your statement it seems OK.

Comment: I've added some code to capture the essence of what I'm trying to do

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel Did you ever solve this?  Use request.form or change location of control creation?

Answer (score 2):

If the controls really need to be created in OnInit or CreateChildControls then one thing you can do is get the value of your static control from the Request.Form[] collection during OnInit.

So instead of doing:

```
string selected = myDropDown.SelectedValue;
```

you do

```
string selected = Request.Form[myDropDownUniqueID];
```

... where myDropDownID is the 'unique id' assigned to myDropDown. Note that usually this will be the same as the 'id' assigned to the control, unless it is inside a control container.

This is effectively pulling the value straight out of the HTML Form data that gets sent to the server, rather than waiting for ASP.NET to unpack it into the properties of the control.

Comment: @codeulike: Request.Form[myDropDownUniqueID] seems to work great when the drop down id defined standalone and not in any container.

Any suggestions as to how to get the unique ID when the drop down is part of an EditItemTemplate in a Gridview? I need to get to the uniqueId of the dropdown for the current row being edited.

Comment: I guess that during OnInit the GridView control will not be ready to tell you what it contains. Your best bet may be to loop through the GridView control on the previous postback (eg soon after it is databound), extract the UniqieIDs of each control and store them in Session[] for later use.

Comment: Or ... the UniqueIDs that get assigned to controls in GridViews are fairly predictable (have a look at the source of the page that gets rendered). You might be able to exploit that. Also you might be able to loop through the Forms[] collection looking for keys that match the pattern.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid having to hard code ASPNET generated control names in code. Is there no other way to obtain the post back value in OnInit?

Comment: This might work: When the grid goes into edit mode to show the edit template, inspect the row (or all rows that are in edit mode) and use the Control.FindControl() method to find the DropDown. You can then check the UniqueID property of the control and keep a record of it somewhere (in Session[] for example)

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to check if the grid is in edit mode inside OnInit since ViewState has not been loaded as yet? or would you?

Comment: I was thinking of registering a call to a javascript function which accepts a row index as a parameter, for the 'onclick' event of the Edit link button in the OnDataBound event of the gridview. The javascript function would then set a hidden field indicating the current row being edited. Then when we are in OnInit we can query for the row index to find the row being edited. Maybe I can adapt the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228549/get-gridview-selected-row-datakey-in-javascript

Comment: ^^ You aim to get the uniqueID of the control _on the previous postback_ so that you can use it in the OnInit event of the next one. Not sure if that works though. Your javascript plan sounds feasible.

Comment: It's a pain and quite unfortunate that the runtime and the framework can't assist in providing a mechanism that allows a developer to specify loading the viewstate for a control

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects I add controls dynamically in Page_Load.

I use SaveControlState and LoadControlState to manually save and load the control view state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadcontrolstate.aspx

Shay.