# asp.net gridview tr id unique for jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, webforms

I have created a ASP.NET WebForms Gridview and I need to access each row (e.g. the `<TR>`) of the table in javascript/jquery....
Unfortunately it looks like the `<tr>`'s generated by the gridview all have the same ID!

Is there a way to change this?  Any ideas how I could access a particular row in javascript (basically I am trying to call a method and pass it the row id that it needs to access).

--- More Info ---

```
 <asp:GridView ..>
    <Columns>
      <asp:Templatefield>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList onchange="javascript:EnableControls('ROWIDHERE')">
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Its the one change of the dropdownlist that needs to know what row its on!

Comment: This link may help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/JavaRowSelect.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately its a control inside the row that needs the row, will edit question to provide more info

Comment: Also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228549/get-gridview-selected-row-datakey-in-javascript.  A possible idea there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let jQuery manange your handlers, you could do something like this using `.closest()`.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
    // do something with the row
});
```

This will traverse the ancestors until you get to the `<tr>`.

If you wanted to stay with the inline handlers, then try something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList onchange="javascript:EnableControls(this)">

function EnableControls(elem) {
    var $tr = $(elem).closest('tr'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the example code for the gridview so that we can compare the templates?

One option of the top of my head would be to give each  a class element which uses an inline code block to assign a unique class based on the index for instance. Here's an example:

```
<tr class='uniqueClass<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
```

This way your  elements would be produced as

```
<TR class='uniqueClass0' />
<TR class='uniqueClass1' />
<TR class='uniqueClass2' />
```

From here, you can then identify the  you require in jquery by simply using

```
var rowIndexRequired = 1;
var requireRow = $('.uniqueClass'+rowIndexRequired);
```

If you provide more detail then I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access it top down via:

```
$("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").find("tr:eq(0)")
```

or use parents to search up:

```
//this reference to element
$(this).parents("tr:first")
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is a control inside the row that needs to reference the row, can't you just use something like this:

`$(".myControlClass").parents("tr")`

to reference the row?  You control would have a class assigned to it so you can select it that way.  I don't know what the markup looks like, but this may be a good start.