# how to get the DataKey value in gridview using jquery or javascript? PLEASE READ THE CODE AS WELL BEFORE ANSWER

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a gridview and i am adding two buttons "**Edit and Delete**" dynamically(by code). Here is my HTML Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4"
                BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#E2E2E2" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="test" BackColor="#E2E2E2" Height="25px" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2E2E2" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my Code Behind Code ::

```
 private void BindData(DataTable dtColumns)
{
    GridView1.Columns.Clear();
    String Query = "";
    DataTable dtSearchItems = (DataTable)ViewState["dtSearchItems"];
    String PrimaryKey = "";
    if (ViewState["PrimaryKey"] != null)
    {
        PrimaryKey = ViewState["PrimaryKey"].ToString();
    }
    if (dtColumns != null)
    {
        String Columns = "";
        if (dtColumns.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtColumns.Rows)
            {
                Columns += dr["OrignalColumn"].ToString() + ",";
            }
            Columns = Columns.TrimEnd(',');
            Query = "Select " + PrimaryKey + " , " + Columns + " from " + TableName + " where 1 = 1 ";
        }
        else
        {
            Query = "Select *," + PrimaryKey + " from " + TableName + " where 1 = 1 ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Query = "Select *," + PrimaryKey + " from " + TableName + " where 1 = 1 ";
    }
    if (dtSearchItems != null)
    {
        if (dtSearchItems.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtSearchItems.Rows)
            {
                Query += " " + dr["AndOr"].ToString() + " " + dr["ColumnName"].ToString() + " " + ClsStaticSearch.ReturnOperationSymbol(dr["Operation"].ToString(), dr["Value"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Query = Query;
        }
    }

    DataTable dtOutPutResult = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
    dtOutPutResult.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { PrimaryKey };

    if (dtOutPutResult.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dcDtOutPutResult in dtOutPutResult.Columns)
        {
            foreach (DataRow drDtColumns in dtColumns.Rows)
            {
                if (drDtColumns["OrignalColumn"].ToString() == dcDtOutPutResult.ColumnName)
                {
                    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                    bfield.DataField = dcDtOutPutResult.ColumnName;
                    bfield.HeaderText = drDtColumns["DisplayColumn"].ToString();
                    GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);
                }
            }
        }

        TemplateField t = new TemplateField();
        DynamicTemplate mt = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.Item);

        Button btnEdit = new Button();
        btnEdit.ID = "btnEdit";
        btnEdit.Visible = true;
        btnEdit.OnClientClick = "return confirm_Edit();";
        btnEdit.Text = " Submit";
        btnEdit.CssClass = "button";
        btnEdit.Style.Add("margin-right", "5px");
        mt.AddControl(btnEdit, "Text", "Edit");

        Button btnDelete = new Button();
        btnDelete.ID = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm_delete();";
        btnDelete.Visible = true;
        btnDelete.Text = " Submit";
        btnDelete.CssClass = "button";
        mt.AddControl(btnDelete, "Text", "Delete");

        t.ItemTemplate = mt;
        t.HeaderText = "Activity";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(t);
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        lblMessage.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
        lblMessage.Text = "No Record Found.";
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

What i want to do is::

I want to create a generic module for advanced search, that is almost complete, now what i want to do it it is: **i want to add edit and delete functionality to grid also. for that i need to get DataKey Value of the grid for each button's click only by javascript or jquery** because the buttons will not be visible if the page is being post back.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

**using hiddenfield to fetch value is very common solution for this scenario**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="key" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="#" id="getID">Read data key</a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table[id*=gridviewid] a[id*=getID]").click(function() {
            alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=hidden][id*=key]").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you find this tedious, you can find similar questions and solutions below:

[With Jquery](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.in/2010/10/jquery-to-read-datakeynames-value-of.html)

[On mouse over](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?639927-Get-DataKeyNames-Value-in-GridView-OnMouseOver)

[Code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/510800/howplusiplusgetplusgridplusviewplusdatakeyplusvalu)

[Fetching selected row datakey - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228549/get-gridview-selected-row-datakey-in-javascript)

Comment: your title didnt explain about the scenario or a mention any particular situation. in that case, if you want all the people to read your 40 lines of code than answering it, better mention it in the title.

Comment: @codebrain: If his problem needs more explanation or code then its fine to add it in question .